# register form + insert query do not work how to fix it

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have a register form that required some input from user. The form was working fine but now it doesn't insert any value to the database. Can anyone help me?

I will display all the code but what I need is help about the insert query:

## register.php

```
<?php require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); ?>

<?php
function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_id'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

 //default value
$message = "Fields Marcked with an [*] are Required";
  $username = "";
  $fname = "";
  $lname = "";
  $specialization = "";
  $email = "";
  $pass1 = "";
  $pass2 = "";
  $governorate="";
  $district = "";
  $village = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
  $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
  $pass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);
  $bdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birthdate']);


  $specialization = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['specialization']);
  $governorate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['governorate']);
  @$district = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['district']);
  @$village = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['village']);


      var_dump($fname);
      var_dump($username);
      var_dump($governorate);
      var_dump($email);

  //error handeling
  if((!$username)||(!$fname)||(!$lname)||(!$email)||(!$pass1)||(!$pass2)||(!$specialization)||(!$governorate)||(!$district)||(!$village)){
  $message = "**** Please insert the Required Fields below ****<br />";

      if($fname == "")
     {
         $message = $message . "Enter First name<br/>";
     }
      if($lname == "")
     {
         $message = $message . "Enter Last name<br/>";
     }

     if( $specialization == 0)
     {
         $message = $message . "Select Your Job<br />";

     }
     if($governorate == 0)
     {
         $message = $message . "Select Your Governorate<br />";
     }

     if($district == '0')
     {
         $message = $message . "Select Your District<br />";
     }
     if($village == '0')
     {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Village<br />";

     }
     if($email == "")
     {
         $message = $message . "Enter Email Adress<br/>";
     }
      if ($username == "") {
        $message = $message . "Enter User Name<br/>";
      }

      if($pass1 == "")
     {
         $message = $message . "Enter password<br/>";
     }

      if($pass2 == "")
     {
         $message = $message . "rechek the password <br/>";
     }


 } 

     elseif(strlen($pass1) <= 8)
    {
         $message = $message . "Your Password must be at least 8 charachters<br />";
    }
   else if($pass1!=$pass2){
   $message = "your password do not match!";
 }
 else
 {
   //securing the data
   $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
   $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
   $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
   //$pass1 = sha1($pass1);

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   // checking for duplicate
   $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the username");
   $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

    $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT email_address FROM user WHERE email_address = '$email'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the email");
   $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

    if($count_username > 0){
     $message = " your username is alredy in use";
    }elseif($count_email > 0){
      $message = "your email is alredy in use";
    }
   else{

      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, governorate, district, village, birth_date, email_address, specialization, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$governorate', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())")or die("could not insert data"); 




    $message = "you have  now been registered";
    //from the social website


        if ($query) 
       {
       $_SESSION['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
       $_SESSION['login'] = 'true';
       $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
       }
?>
```

Comment: You need to read about SQL injection. ALWAYS use parametrized queries or escaping - and NEVER rely on whatever "safe values check" you eprform.

Comment: please use mysqli or PDO.use placeholders with PDO without using variables directly to the sql commands.MYSQl has been deprecated now

Comment: Instead of dumping the whole copy of code, you need to post only the relevant code that may be problematic - [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Isn't this essentially a dup of the question you asked an hour earlier?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate code in files. You have wrote long like story. 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //such type of code so many times. Mine code is not good but better than yours. Try to divide code in functions and separate each logic in functions. So that it is easily understandable and changeable (change in 1 place should change in all places). Try to separate JS, HTML, PHP, error handling, etc. I haven't wrote whole working code but show you way, how you can improve.

```
function getPostedField($var){
    if(!empty($_POST[$var]) and ($_POST[$var]!=0) ){
        $var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
        return ($var);
    }
    return false;
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $fields = array('username','fname','lname'.....); 
    $errors = 0;
    $posted_arr = array();
    foreach($fields as $field){
        $value = getPostedField($field);
        if($value){
            $posted_arr[$field] = $value;
        }else{
            $errors++;
        $error_msg .= "<p>$field should not be empty.</p>";
        }
    }
    if($posted_arr['pass1']==$posted_arr['pass2'] and (strlen($posted_arr['pass2']<=8) ) ){
    $errors++;
    }
    //do more checking here
    if($error==0){
    $query = "insert into `table`";
        foreach($fields as $field){
        $query .= "`$field`='".$posted_arr[$field]."',";
        }
    $len = strlen($query) - 1;
    $query = substr($query,0,$len); //removing last ,
    $sql_query = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```